# Custom comment markers in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

When you have `todo:` in your comments, intellij can detect it and show it in the todo list. How can I make some custom markers to be recognized? For example, `config:`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look in Settings, in Editor / TODO. You can set patterns and other options for this feature there.

[image: Screenshot of Settings / Editor / TODO]

Answer (score 1):

This is like a TODO. See the official IntelliJ documentation; https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/using-todo.html.